# Сделать отступ: как подвинуть основной текст вправо?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 8%;
}

p {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

img {
  margin-left: ;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Harry Potter and the Cursed Child</p>
  <h1><a href="https://google.com/">Гарри Поттер и проклятое дитя</a></h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="text">Пока Гарри Поттер пытается бороться с прошлым, которое в прошлом ставаться совсем не хочет, его младший сын Альбус сражается с грузом семейного наследия, которое ему никогда не нравилось. Прошлое и настоящее зловеще переплетаются, а отцу и сыну
        становится очевидной нелегкая истина: мрак подчас приходит из самых неожиданных мест.</td>
      <td><img src="img/book.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в класс `text` добавить внутренний отступ слева:

```css
.text {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```